# How to get the responses of only the spike added in the soak test in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

My scenario is I'm running 50 threads for 15 mins and the running 100 threads for 15 mins. The total time of the of the test is 21 mins.
The 50 threads will start running after 10 seconds, slowly ramping up, for 5 mins 50 threads will run simultaneously and then after 5 mins 100 threads with start running slowly with ramping up and run for 15 mins.
After 100 threads finish the 50 threads will continue there running.
The image below will show you the jp@gc thread group

[The image will show you the jp@gc ultimate thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5jAr.png)

I only want the responses (maily in graph format ) drilled down to only when 100 users are present, I dont want aggregate of all the soak test.How can this be done? I have also tried loading the jtl.gz file on https://loadosophia.org , it also gives the aggregate reportwhich i dont want.
I only want the specific report of the spike added of 100 users for 15 mins
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grep your file to only select the interval of time you want and use it to generate file.

Another option is to use this method:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/

With this plugin:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/

And use the fields :

- Start Offset
- End Offset

Comment: hello, I do get the graphs, but the problem is it dosent show the maximum value attend, the graphs generated are totally different than what are dislayed in jmeter.